# Question 12.2.1 of Bondy's Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The exact question is:

> A certain bridge club has a special rule to the effect that four members
> may play together only if no two of them have previously partnered each other. At
> one meeting fourteen members, each of whom has previously partnered five others,
> turn up. Three games are played and then proceedings come to a halt because of
> the club rule. Just as the members are preparing to leave, a new member, unknown
> to any one of them, arrives. Show that at least one more game can now be played.

If we construct a graph on $14$ vertices representing the $14$ people, connecting $v_i$ and $v_j$ if and only if person $i$ and $j$ have not been partnered with each other, we have the following equivalent formulation:

> Show that if $|G| = 14$ and $G$ is a $8$-regular graph, if after removing $3$-copies of $K_4$ from it, $G$ does not contain another $K_4$, then this new graph contains a triangle.

It suffices to find a triangle in this new graph because it implies that the $3$ people involved in the triangle has not been paired up with one another. These $3$ people, along with the additional member, can now play a new game.

So far, these are the results I've established.

Before removing the $3$ copies of $K_4$, $e(G) = 56$.

After removing the $3$ copies of $K_4$, $e(G) = 56 - 3 \times 6 =  38$.

If $G$ does not contain a triangle, then by Mantel's theorem, $e(G) = 14^2/ 4 = 49$. This doesn't give a contradiction as hoped, since $49 > 38$.

I've also tried using the stronger version of Mantel's theorem, which is $e(G) \leq \alpha(G) \beta(G)$, where $\alpha(G)$ is the cardinality of the maximum independent set of $G$, and $\beta(G)$ is the cardinality of the minimum vertex cover of $G$. But I can't find a way to link it with the fact that $G$ minus three copies of $K_4$ no longer contains another $K_4$.

I've also established that after the removal of three copies of $K_4$, there still will be at least two vertices of degree $8$, and the minimum degree of the new graph is at leasat $2$.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure of your interpretation of "only if no two of them have previously partnered each other"?  I mean, should we count opposing players as having partnered?  If you interpret this as no, in a bridge game you have two pairs of partners.  So after a game is played, you only remove two edges.  This means that after 3 games, you have 56 - 6 = 50 edges, which is conveniently just above 49.

Comment: Ι was just typing what @ManuelLafond said. The question as written fails to clarify that in a game of bridge four players are divided into **two teams**. Only players in **one** team are partners.

Comment: Ah, good point, that's probably what the question meant. Thanks for pointing that out to me. Then I guess this problem is solved then.